# visualize linear regression model fitting python

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, model-fitting

how i can visualize my model?

i have this data

```
X, Y = datasets.make_regression(n_targets=3, n_features=2, noise=10, random_state=42)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y)
```

have `class LinearRegression:` where i'm writing algorithm to Linear Regression w/ gradient descent

fitting this

```
model = LinearRegression()
mse = model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

how i should visualize this with `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 0):

we can just use `plt.plot` with our model as arg and `plt.show()` to show this

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.plot(mse)
plt.show()
```